# firebase Functions TimeStamp convert it to string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

```
const signupTime =admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    
    database.ref(`/admin/vendorOrder/${vendor}/${userID}`).set(signupTime);
    console.log(signupTime);
```

i want the time value
while in database it returns correctly
[image]

in consol log it returns
[image]

how do i make it return value in string

also

```
database.ref(`/admin/vendorOrder/${vendor}/${userID}/${signupTime}/order`).set(order);
```

returns error
[image]
kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp), with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` you get "a **placeholder** value for auto-populating the current timestamp **as determined by the Firebase servers**".

In other words `signupTime` does not contain the value of the timestamp, since this one is **set on the server** (the back-end) when you write to the database.

If you want to get this value in your Cloud Function (or in a front-end), you need to query the newly set database node, as follows, for example:

```
  const signupTime = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

  const database = admin.database();
  const ref = database.ref(`/admin/vendorOrder/${vendor}/${userID}`);

  ref
    .set(signupTime)
    .then(() => {
      return ref.get();
    })
    .then((snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```